# Set internal shortcut when creating page from code in EPiServer

Tags: episerver

How can I set an internal shortcut on a new page that is create from code-behind?

Stig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
int shortcutId = ...;

newPage.LinkType = PageShortcutType.Shortcut;
newPage.Property["PageShortcutLink"].Value = new PageReference(shortcutId);
```

Comment: not sure why I didn't try this but i sure did the trick :) grazie mille

Comment: You should consider using the MetaDataProperties class' constants, instead of typing out a full string name for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call CreateWritableClone method because the property PageShortcutLink is read-only

here my code:

```
PageReference prtest = new PageReference(21602);
PageReference prlinked = new PageReference(21603);
PageData pdtest = DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(prtest);
PageData pdClone = pdtest.CreateWritableClone();
pdClone.LinkType = PageShortcutType.Shortcut;
pdClone.Property["PageShortcutLink"].Value = prlinked;
DataFactory.Instance.Save(pdClone, SaveAction.Publish);
```

Answer (score 0):

Next code did the job for me (but it is for external links):

```
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(release.link))
        {
            page.LinkType = PageShortcutType.External;
            page.LinkURL = release.link;
        }
```

Actually, I needed to set an external link url and tried to put something like:

```
page.Property["PageExternalUrl"].Value = "https://somethingnotsimpleaddress.com";
```

but then I got an exception that it is not possible to set not "simpleaddress" to the property. That's why I used 'LinkUrl' instead.